# How can i send POST requests through ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have simple functions in my ember application that just do stuff like adding user vote to a post, or follow another user, and i was wondering how can I do this in ember?

I don't want to use this

```
jQuery.post('/posts/' + post.id + '/votes');
```

Comment: well, ember uses also jQuery under the hood, so you could also do `Ember.ajax(...)`

Comment: ajax example: http://lithifi.tumblr.com/post/18989616093/emberjs-json-post-saving.  If you want change **$.ajax** used in the article to  **Ember.ajax** as recommended by @intuitivepixel.

Comment: Problem is I'm using specific URL, and i have `x-app-id` that i'm using too, And using ajax will not inherit from ember definition.

Comment: Also `Ember.ajax` returns error. `[Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajax' ]`

Comment: Oh sorry, it's `Ember.$.ajax(...)`

Comment: @intuitivepixel ok, but still doesn't inherit from Ember's main `ajax` method i had custom, the request is send to Webapp URL to the API